# MySQL Assign matches only once in an update query

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables, one with participants and their ranking and another one with voucher-codes and their rank. I'd like to assign a voucher-code with the correct rank to each participant, but make sure every voucher-code is used only once, of course.

```
Table A:                             Table B:
pid | name | rank | voucherid        voucherid | rank | code | used
1   | Max  | 10   | null             1         | 10   | AAA  | 0
2   | Joe  | 20   | null             2         | 10   | BBB  | 0
3   | Eva  | 10   | null             3         | 20   | CCC  | 0
                                     4         | 20   | DDD  | 0
```

I'm looking for an update query producing this result:

```
Table A:
pid | name | rank | voucherid
1   | Max  | 10   | 1
2   | Joe  | 20   | 3
3   | Eva  | 10   | 2
```

The following doesn't work, because it assigns the same voucher to multiple participants:

```
UPDATE A
JOIN B ON A.`rank` = B.`rank`
SET A.`voucherid` = B.`voucherid`
WHERE
   A.`voucherid` IS NULL AND
   B.`used` = 0
;
-
Result:
Table A:
pid | name | rank | voucherid
1   | Max  | 10   | 1
2   | Joe  | 20   | 3
3   | Eva  | 10   | 1 !!!
```

I will of course update the voucher table B to set the `used` column to `1` afterwards.

Comment: To make sure the voucher is only used once you can add a `UNIQUE KEY` to `A.voucherid`, but you won't be able to update all rows with that query, since it will try to insert duplicates, the whole update will fail

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer using `user variables`, that's why I'm answering my own question.

The idea is to use a counter as second comparison variable, to make sure that voucher1 with rank1 is assigned to one participant and voucher2 with rank1 to another participant.

The MySQL query is quite cumbersome. That's why I'm probably using PHP to solve the problem. But I wanted to share it, at least:

```
UPDATE `A` AS ua
JOIN (

  SELECT
    ta.`participantid`, ta.`rank`, 
    (@ca := IF(@pa = ta.`rank`, @ca + 1, 0)) AS `counter`, 
    @pa := ta.`rank`
  FROM `A` AS ta, (SELECT @ca := 0, @pa := 0) AS ia
  WHERE
    ta.`voucherid` IS NULL
  ORDER BY `rank` ASC

) AS a ON a.`pid` = ua.`pid`
JOIN (

  SELECT
    tb.`voucherid`, tb.`rank`,
    (@cb := IF(@pb = tb.`rank`, @cb + 1, 0)) AS `counter`,
    @pb := tb.`rank`
  FROM `B` AS tb, (SELECT @cb := 0, @pb := 0) AS ib
  WHERE
    tb.`used` = 0
  ORDER BY `rank` ASC

) AS b ON (b.`rank` = a.`rank` AND b.`counter` = a.`counter`)
JOIN `B` AS ub ON ub.`voucherid` = b.`voucherid`
SET
  ua.`voucherid` = b.`voucherid`,
  ub.`used` = 1
;
```

It worked in the test cases I prepared, but according to the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) you cannot rely on the order of evaluation for expressions. Therefore the `@pa := ta.rank` might be executed before the `IF(@pa = ta.rank)`, which would lead to wrong results.